# Issue loading Visualforce page: all queries are executed twice, what i'm missing?

Tags: visualforce, soql, visualforce-component

I am managing a visualforce page, which on loading run all the queries twice, both queries made from the controller of the page or from the custom components. I don't understand how this can happen. We found this because we had a reached limit of the SOQL, after that we made some optimizations, but we don't understand why all queries are executed twice. 
The page use a lot of custom components, and I don't know if they can interfere with the page in some way... anyone had a similar experience or know what happen?

thnks in advance... 
Klodjan

**The page is the following...**

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Dossier_Cliente__tab" title="Dossier Cliente" StandardController="Account" extensions="CruscottoCliente">
    <c:KillerStyle />

    <apex:message />
    <apex:enhancedList height="400" rowsPerPage="10" listId="{!ListViewId}" customizable="true" rendered="{! !(bId)}"/>

    <apex:detail relatedList="false" subject="{!Account.Id}" title="true" rendered="{!bId}" inlineEdit="true"/>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(bId)}">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.SendDunningLetter}" action="{!Sollecito}"/>
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!Account.Invio_Sollecito__c}"/>
            <Br/>
            <Br/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!(bId)}">
        <div id="crabbtabs">
            <ul>
                <li style="display:{!IF( Account.Mondo_Scuola__c , 'None', '')}">
                    <a href="#tabs-1">{!$Label.ExpiredAmountsAgeing}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">{!$Label.Cases}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">{!$Label.Services}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-11">Fruitori</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4">{!$Label.Addresses}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5">{!$Label.StatementOfAccount}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6">{!$Label.RepaymentPlans}</a></li>
                <li style="display:{!IF( Account.Mondo_Scuola__c , 'None', '')}">
                    <a href="#tabs-7">{!$Label.BalanceVariations}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-8">{!$Label.Activities}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-9">{!$Label.Documentation}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-10">Chatter</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1" >
                <div style="display:{!IF( Account.Mondo_Scuola__c , 'None', '')}">
                    <apex:pageblock title="{!$Label.ExpiredAmountsAgeing}" id="StackedChart">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection >
                            <c:StckdChart8Val StkData="{!StkData}" MinRes="0" MaxRes="{!MaxRes}" TopSteps="5" BottomSteps="10"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        <apex:pageblockSection >
                            <c:Chart2Val ChartData="{!pieData}" MinRes="0" MaxRes="100" Steps="5" TitoloGenerale="Ageing" TitoloAsse1="# Movimenti" TitoloAsse2="Scaduto â‚¬"/>
                        </apex:pageblockSection>
                    </apex:pageblock>
                    <c:RiepilogoScaduto ChartData="{!pieData}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Pratica__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Servizio__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-4">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Indirizzi__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-5">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Movimento__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-6">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Piano_di_Rientro__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-7" style="display:{!IF( Account.Mondo_Scuola__c , 'None', '')}">
                <c:TblPage sObj="CredMan__Storico_Movimentazione_Pratiche__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente" NomeParent="{!Account.Name}"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-8">
                <c:TblAttUltimoAnno TipoAtt="{!TipoAtt}" LastYear="{!LastYear}" mMesiAtt="{!mMesiAtt}"/>
                <c:TblPage sObj="Task" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-9">
                <c:TblPage sObj="Attachment" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>

                <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.UploadNewDocuments}">
                    <c:FileUpload parentId="{!Account.Id}"/>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-10">
                <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!Account.Id}" showHeader="false"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-11">
                <c:TblPage sObj="Servizi_Item__c" IdParent="{!Account.Id}" sParent="Cliente"/>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It looks like we might need a little more information, like the controller code and possibly the rest of the page that you didn't put in here.

Comment: it's likely not in the *page* markup, but in the controller code or the component markup. Can you please post those?

Comment: the page finish there, is missing just '</apex:page>'

Comment: The problem to post the code, is that there is a 3/4 level three of dependences and is complex to post all code, anyway I just try to post a bit more code...

Comment: Which queries are running twice?  ALL of the queries, or only some of them?  Have you tried putting in debugs near every query to ensure you are hitting the debugs twice also near each one?  Is it only queries on components getting hit twice, or is it queries in your main controller also?

Comment: In the start we seen, analysing the debug log of salesforce, that the queries was present twice, and that surprised a bit us. After that we tried to simplify the page removing the components. Without any component the queries are not present twice (without components is execute correctly just one query ) . 
After this test, we added elements incrementally. Testing and debugging, we observed that, as we add the component "TblPage", all the queries made from such component are executed twice, we don't understand why.

Comment: Another detail discovered along the tests is that, if we set the <apex:page .... readOnly="true" > the queries are executed just once...